# Programatic navigation in SwiftUI for universal links

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to navigate programmatically to a correct screen when using universal links.  This should be done in the scene delegate but I'm confused how should I navigate to the right view?

I have tried this but there is weird behavior after clicking navigate back the view gets pushed and pop automatically without me pressing something.

```
class AppState: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var selectedId: String?
}
```

And this is how I use it in the list to navigate automatically.

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), tag: item.id, selection:  self.$appState.selectedId)
```

This is what I was getting: https://swiftui-lab.com/bug-navigationlink-isactive/

Comment: You need to share more code, so we can reproduce the issue. Provided code works fine.

Comment: I have the issue when the detail view is opened, then when I click back the view goes back to the list, then again goes to detail view and again to the list. Is this some kind of known bug or something?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it's hard to reproduce your issue.

You may try this template based on the provided samples:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let text: String
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedId: Int?

    let items: [Item] = [
        Item(id: 0, text: "Zero"),
        Item(id: 1, text: "One"),
        Item(id: 2, text: "Two"),
        Item(id: 3, text: "Three"),
        Item(id: 4, text: "Four"),
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var appState = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.appState.items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), tag: item.id, selection: self.$appState.selectedId) {
                    Text(item.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.text)
    }
}
```

Tested in Xcode 11.5, iOS 13.5.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Have you ever tried to navigate programmatically through multiple lists? For example from item list to item models list, and then to detail view?